# Rollover images, when clicked show movable pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on a website that has some images that I need to to rollover when the mouse goes over them to add some extra spark to the site.  But I also need the images, when clicked, to show a **movable** pop up window with another image inside it, larger.

If anyone could get me started in the right direction/code/script It would greatly be appreciated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has a [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event you can add to your images.  In order to pop a nice dialog you should look into an existing plug-in such as [MopBox](http://ajaxmint.com/2010/01/mopbox-a-draggable-lightbox/) or maybe roll your own using [jQuery UI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).